# Ruby Action Mailer: How can I send daily emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, notifications, actionmailer

I'm just wondering, in a Ruby on Rails 3 application, if I want to send users an email notification once per day, rather than with every notification, how would I set that up with Action Mailer?

Specifically, would there be a way to run a mailer at, say, 6:00pm every day?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to run a cron job (Linux / Mac servers). This is fairly simple with the Whenever gem which abstracts the actual writing of cron job syntax into a convenient set of ruby methods, which you can programmatically change.

[This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby) goes over it pretty well.